# Graph modelling (Social network)

Tags: graph, neo4j

I'm learning about graphs making a social network. I'm stucked trying to represent a three nodes relationship, let me explain.

I have (user_a) who's inviting (user_b) to (event). I can model it this way:
(user_a)-[invites]->(user_b)-[wasInvitedTo]->(event)

But with this model i cant know the whole way because user_b it´s gonna be invited from many users to many events. I know that (user_a) invites (user_b) but i don't know to which event and on the other hand I know that (user_b) was invited to (event) but i don't know who invited him.
A case study is when I try to notify (user a) that (user_b) has invited (event).

Am I explaining myself? It's hard to explain this and harder to explain it not in my main language.

The only solution i can approach is to set ids in the relations:
(user_a)-[invites {to: event_id}]->(user_b)-[wasInvitedTo {from: user_a_id]->(event)
But I don't think it's a good solution.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Could you add an image or a code structure to illustrate your question? The formatting and the language makes it pretty hard to read and comprehend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

In this instance I'd probably want to pull out an 'Invitation' concept as a node in your graph (here, the green numbered node):

```
MERGE (a: User { name: 'Anne' })
MERGE (b: User { name: 'Bob' })
MERGE (c: User { name: 'Chris' })
MERGE (d: User { name: 'Diane' })
MERGE (e: Event { name: 'The Big Party' })
MERGE (i: Invitation)
MERGE (a)-[:CREATED]->(i)
MERGE (i)-[:SENT_TO]->(b)
MERGE (i)-[:SENT_TO]->(c)
MERGE (i)-[:SENT_TO]->(d)
MERGE (i)-[:RELATES_TO]->(e)
RETURN *
```

[image]

One *User* can invite multiple other *Users* to multiple *Events*, by creating new *Invitation* nodes. They could feasibly create multiple *Invitations* for the same *Event*, if for example they wanted to use different text or images for some set of *Users* than others.

You can also hang metadata off the invitation itself, like date sent, text/images etc.